# Counting the number of fields in a column that are consecutively same

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, gawk

My input file looks like this:

```
bio, john
chem, john
lang, john
math, dina
math, john
math, matt
lang, matt
```

I want to count rows where the name is same consecutively only once. For this input, I want to get:

```
john 2
dina 1
matt 1
```

Any way I can do this using sed or awk? I am totally lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the previous value in a variable, if the values are different, increment the number in an associative array.

```
awk -F ', ' '{if ($2 != p) { c[$2]++ } p=$2}
             END { for (k in c) {print k, c[k]} }'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want something quick'n'dirty, you could use `uniq` to de-duplicate the contiguous entries, then sort + count duplicates:

```
$ cut -d, -f2 file | uniq | sort | uniq -c
      1  dina
      2  john
      1  matt
```